# Amchart's Serial Chart page gets freezed when used in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, amcharts

I am using [Amchart's](https://www.amcharts.com/) serial chart in ionic framework. I have rendered the serial chart using

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
                    {
                        "type": "serial",
                        "categoryField": "Name",
                        "rotate": true,
                        "angle": 30,
                        "depth3D": 40,
                        "startDuration": 1,
                        "fontSize": 10,
                        "theme": "default",
                        "precision": 4,
                        "creditsPosition": "bottom-right",
                        "responsive": {
                            "enabled": true
                        },
                        "categoryAxis": {
                            "gridPosition": "middle",
                            "title": "Name",
                            "inside": true
                        },
                        "graphs": [
                            {
                                "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[Name]]:[[value]]",
                                "fillAlphas": 1,
                                "id": "AmGraph-1",
                                "title": "X",
                                "type": "column",
                                "valueField": "X"
                            },
                            {
                                "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[Name]]:[[value]]",
                                "fillAlphas": 1,
                                "id": "AmGraph-2",
                                "title": "Y",
                                "type": "column",
                                "valueField": "Y"
                            },
                            {
                                "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[Name]]:[[value]]",
                                "fillAlphas": 1,
                                "id": "AmGraph-3",
                                "title": "Z",
                                "type": "column",
                                "valueField": "Z"
                            }                              
                          ],
                        "valueAxes": [
                            {
                                "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                                "title": "Amount"
                            }
                        ],
                        "titles": [
                            {
                                "id": "Title-1",
                                "text": "SUMMARY"
                            }
                        ],
                        "legend": {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "useGraphSettings": true,
                            "position": "bottom"
                        },
                        "dataProvider": $scope.data,
                        "listeners": [{
                            "event": "clickGraphItem",
                            "method": function (event) {
                                $scope.SelectedX = event.item.category;
                                $scope.SelectedContext = event.item.dataContext;
                                $scope.LoadDetailsData($scope.SelectedX, $scope.SelectedContext.Period);                         
                            }
                        }]

                    }
                );
            chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);
            zoomChart();

            function zoomChart() {
                chart.zoomToIndexes(0, chart.dataProvider.length - (chart.dataProvider.length - 3));
            }
```

I am opening IonicModal on click of graph items and creating another chart. When I close the IonicModal, page which contains the above chart gets freezed untill I press hardware back button.

I am using pie charts few places but not facing this issue on those pages. It seems there is some issue with the serial chart only.

Using IonicModal from template URL option to open Modal -

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('template.html', { scope: $scope })
 .then(function (modal) {
     $scope.sortModal = modal;
 });

$scope.sortShow = function () {
    //alert('inside show');
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.sortModal.show();
        $scope.LoadDetailsChart(); //creating next chart data
    }, 0);
};

$scope.sortClose = function () {
    $scope.sortModal.hide();
};

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    $scope.sortModal.remove();
});
```

Comment: Please provide any plunker url for same.

Comment: I dont have any plunker created for this. I can post code here.

Comment: A plunker/fiddle that reproduces this would really help. How many datapoints are in your serial chart?

Comment: Ok..let me see if I can somehow post the part of code on plunker/fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to add paneventenabled property as false here. As per amcharts docs,

> This setting affects touch-screen devices only. If a chart is on a page, and panEventsEnabled are set to true, the page won't move if the user touches the chart first. If a chart is big enough and occupies all the screen of your touch device, the user won’t be able to move the page at all. That's why the default value is "false". If you think that selecting/panning the chart or moving/pinching the map is a primary purpose of your users, you should set panEventsEnabled to true.